# List.getSize() returns different result when run in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse

I found something strange about an eclipse debugger.
First of all, when a program runs as a simple Java Application, everything is ok, but when I use debugger some references become null so that I catch NullPointerException.

Here is much more strange example:

```
System.out.println("the list size is " + list.getSize());
System.out.println("the list size is " + list.getSize());
System.out.println("the list size is " + list.getSize());
System.out.println("the list size is " + list.getSize());
```

When I start a program the output is : 50, 50, 50, 50.

But when I use debugger the output is : 50, 49, 48, 47. That is REALLY strange, because getSize() method changes nothing.

Comment: Do you modify your list from another thread? Post your list creating code and any code that may modify the list. Do you have any watch expressions that may modify the list?

Comment: Clearly, your debugger is insane (that's a technical term).

Comment: What version of Eclipse ? This bug is to big to be at Eclipse level.

Comment: We really need to see more code (although the threading hint was a good one), especially since getSize() and list are custom methods/classes (because no getSize() method exists on java.util.List... only size())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any custom code in the debugger ("change value" in variables view accepts statements) that might change the list? Like `list.remove()` as a custom value for some variable?

Also check the "detail formatters" for the variables in the variables view, whether there is some code there for this list or some other variable.

Comment: And what will you suggest abot NullPointerExceptions? Why could it be?

Comment: NullPointers are strange, unless you explicitly pause the debugger and "change value" of the variable to null. Is it possible that you have some "detail formatter" code that make this list null, as a side effect?

Comment: Can you crosscheck, just to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible if the list is created just before and with a single threaded application.

Comment: Possible if there in some custom code in "detail formatters", for instance

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is really strange, but it is a fact =(